# Base Storyboard Changes Not Reflected in Localized Storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization, uistoryboard

I have a localized Storyboard (Base and Spanish), and I just realized that after making some changes to the storyboard it did not make the corresponding changes on the Spanish version. Some of the changes I made were button color, added a new label, etc.

Any ideas as to why this happened? I'm assuming there is a correct flow that I did not follow for making updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that on this particular storyboard I had a localized storyboard instead of a localized strings file for the storyboard. In this case you have to edit the two storyboards separately. What I actually wanted was a localized strings file for the storyboard instead of two storyboards.